# Using AWK to convert numbers to 0 or 1

Tags: shell, awk

This might be a simple question but I can't figure it out for the life of me.  I have a file called `keyout.dat` which looks like this:

```
Title
1
Variable
-999
-999
0.234
0.123
-999
-999
0.555
```

The file goes on like this for 500,000 lines.

I want to make a new file where all the `-999` are set to 0 and everything else is set to 1.  I'm sure it's a simple command but I'm having trouble getting it to print to another file.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3):

The comparison itself returns 0 or 1, so you can just print that.

```
awk '{print $1!=-999;}' file > another_file
```

In case you want to keep non-numeric lines:

```
awk '$1!=$1+0 {print $1;next;} {print $1!=-999;}' file > another_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want your `Title` and `Variable` lines intact:

```
awk '!/Title/&&!/Variable/ { $0 = ($1 != -999) }; 1' keyout.dat
```

Or, if the first three lines in the file shall be kept unchanged:

```
awk 'NR > 3 { $0 = ($1 != -999) }; 1' keyout.dat
```

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{$0=($0=="-999")?0:1};1' file
```

Or you can use `sed`:

```
sed -e '/^-999$/s/.*/0/' -e '//!s/.*/1/' file
```

Comment: Your awk solution is wrong; the `$0 = 1` is run every time, so every line comes out `1`.

Comment: @Kevin: Fix it!